# Проблема с условием определения post и get запроса

Tags: php, post, mvc, get

Всем привет!

Проблема возникает при прописании условий в папке аpp/Services/Router.php , получается там я разделяю get запрос от post запроса происходит что то не то и код не срабатывает. Помогите пожалуйста, найти ошибку в коде.

```
public static function enable()
{
    $query = $_GET['q'];
    foreach (self::$list as $route) {  //перебор передаваемых данных
        if($route["uri"] === '/'.$query){ // если такой урл есть то пропускаем дальше
            if($route["post"] === true){ // если это метод пост пропускаем дальше
                $action = new $route["class"]; // создаем экземпляр класса Auth
                $method = $route["method"];  //передача метода
                $action->$method($_POST); //
                die();
            }
        } else { // елси это не пост метод, продолжаем отсюда и переходим по ссылке
            require_once "views/pages/".$route['page'].'.php';
            die();
        }
    }
    self::errors();//нет такого урла? ошибка значит!
}
```

полный код на git-е https://github.com/ksa06/php/tree/main/praktika_oop

Comment: использование `die` в коде - так себе подход.

Comment: Мне вот интересно, кто этому вопросу +1 поставил? Для кого "происходит что-то не то" - это четкая и конкретная постановка вопроса? И почему этот благодетель на вопрос-то тогда не ответил?

Comment: Ипатьев, точно не я, но я хз что делать, не получается и так пытаюсь и сяк. Плохо пытаюсь видимо(

Answer (score 1):

У вас else стоит не там, где нужно. Полагаю, что должно быть так:

```
public static function enable()
    {
        $query = $_GET['q'];
        foreach (self::$list as $route) {  //перебор передаваемых данных
            if($route["uri"] === '/'.$query){ // если такой урл есть то пропускаем дальше
                if($route["post"] === true){ // если это метод пост пропускаем дальше
                    $action = new $route["class"]; // создаем экземпляр класса Auth
                    $method = $route["method"];  //передача метода
                    $action->$method($_POST); //
                    die();
                } else { // если это не пост метод, продолжаем отсюда и переходим по ссылке
                    require_once "views/pages/".$route['page'].'.php';
                    die();
                }
            } 
        }
        self::errors();//нет такого урла? ошибка значит!
    }
```

Comment: Алексей, извините а в чем собственно изменения, Вы прикрепили абсолютно идентичный код, не могу понять в чем подвох.

Comment: Не идентичный, у вас else привязан к if($route["uri"] === '/'.$query){, а должен к if($route["post"] === true){. Посмотрите внимательно на открытие и закрытие фигурных скобок

Comment: ааа, супер! Но к сожалению не помогло. Все равно спасибо!